# Redirect https://example.com to https://www.example.com

Tags: nginx

We got a wildcard certificate from Thawte and this isn't valid for https://example.com.

So we'd like like to forward all requests from https://example.com to https://www.example.com without getting a cert-error.

Is this possible in nginx?

my configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example.ch
                www.example.ch
                api.example.ch;

    if ($host = 'example.ch' ) {
        rewrite  ^/(.*)$  https://www.example.ch/$1 permanent;
    }

    rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443;

    if ($host = 'example.ch' ) {
        rewrite  ^/(.*)$  https://www.example.ch/$1 permanent;
    }

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/example.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/example.key; 

    server_name example.ch
                www.example.ch
                api.example.ch;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Contact Thawte and have your certificate fixed.

Comment: and what CN in your cert? Does it contain example.com AND www.example.com?

Comment: Because the SSL identification happens before nginx sees it, you can't prevent the error. You can mitigate it by using SNI, but that would require getting another certificate and it won't work for all users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't possible, full stop.  SNI notwithstanding, a browser told to go to https://example.com is going to get mighty grumpy about being redirected anywhere else *before* any valid certificate has been presented for example.com - if it didn't, SSL certificates would be substantially pointless.

As others have pointed out, there is no way to support this without getting a certificate that is in some way valid for the initially-requested domain.