# how to re-direct from http(s)://(www.)example.com to https://example.com using Nginx?

Tags: linux, nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, https

Just as the title states.

I found another helpful [Q/A](https://serverfault.com/questions/524333/redirect-https-example-com-to-https-www-example-com), but it does not show how to do it correctly in Nginx settings, I mean the `parameters`. He might mean that `https://exmaple.com` should have a valid handshake before being re-direct to `https://www.example.com` .  In my scenario `https://www.example.com` works great, but `https:example.com` can not be re-direct to `https://www.example.com`.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    rewrite ^ https://example.com$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl on;
    # some other settings, correctly

}
```

But, it when browsing `http://example.com` it is redirected to `https://example.com` but it shows in chrome

````
This site can’t be reached 
example.com unexpectedly closed the connection.
ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED```
````

I want redirect all to `https://example.com`, how ?

--updated--

the `/var/log/nginx/access.log` shows

```
"GET / HTTP/2.0" 301 216 "-"
```

no error in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

Many thanks!!!

Comment: If you browse straight to https:// can you access the site?

Comment: not I can't . `This site can't be reached`

Comment: it has a nginx worker `0.0.0.0:443`, listening alright

Comment: What do the logs show?

Comment: i updated the question. only one line of log `HTTP/2.0 301`

Comment: From the post it's not clear what are you trying to achieve? You said ```but https://example.com can not be re-direct to https://www.example.com``` but from the nginx conf you have described it shouldn't be redirected, because you have only example.com domain with https, but not www.example.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to redirect all traffic to https://www.example.com?

I think you're missing the **ssl** directive in **listen 443 ssl**;

See sample below

## Main Config with HTTPS - www.example.com

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /path/ssl.crt
    other ssl config....
}
```

## Redirect HTTPS naked domain to WWW

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name example.com;
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }
```

## Redirect all HTTP

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. That's clear. Im going to test it.

Answer (score -1):

Like this

```
# Redirect all variations to https://www domain
server {
  listen 80;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/hr.access.log main buffer=128k flush=60;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name www.example.com;

  ssl_certificate /var/lib/acme/certs/x/fullchain;
  ssl_certificate_key /var/lib/acme/certs/x/privkey;

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/hr.access.log main buffer=128k flush=60;

  # Set up preferred protocols and ciphers. TLS1.2 is required for HTTP/2
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

  # This is a cache for SSL connections
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:2m;
  ssl_session_timeout 60m;

  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: I see you you did 1) re-direct all to `https://www.example.com` then 2) redirect it to `https://example.com`  So I should add another vhost listening on port 443 and its `server_name example.com` right?

Comment: There was a small typo sorry. That was copied and pasted from my config, which redirects everything to https://www and I edited it to match what you wanted, but I missed one thing that needed changing. I've updated it now.

Comment: Okay. Now it has 2 re-directions, 3 procedures. 1) requests to `http//example.com` or `http://www.example.com` 2) redirect all to `https://www.example.com` 3) redirect `https://www.example.com` to `https://example.com` . I think it would work.   Did you try a new `server{}` with `server_name example.com` and it functioned well?